# How to let Clion run using "mpiexec"

Tags: mpi, clion

I am currently code for some MPI programs on CLion. When I run the program through the CLion, it only use the single process.

I am aware that I can add some `add_custom_command` to CMake to let it use `mpiexec` .  It is just a bit inconvenient because whenever I run the program, the run made by `add_custom_command` just go in a FLASH and the singe process run will flush the run board.

I was wondering if there is any way to let CLion run automatically with `mpiexec`? I checked the `edit configurations`, but it seems I can only add program arguments.

It might be awkward to ask an IDE question here, if I should not do this, I will delete this question immediately.

Answer (score 4):

You could run program in several processes from terminal. If you're using Cygwin's MPI you could try this in Cygwin Terminal:

```
> cd ThreadsandMPI/MPI/HellowWorld/
> rm helloworld.exe    # if it exists, delete it
> mpic++ helloworld.cpp -o helloworld.exe
> mpirun -np 4 helloworld.exe    # run 4 processes
```

But if you wanna do it without leaving IDE it's possible as well. You need to create a file called `MPI.xml` (in `C:\Users\<yourUserName>\.clion\config\tools` folder) which will contain such code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<toolSet name="MPI">
    <tool name="mpic++" description="MPI C++ compiler" showInMainMenu="true" showInEditor="true" showInProject="true" showInSearchPopup="true" disabled="false" useConsole="true" showConsoleOnStdOut="false" showConsoleOnStdErr="false" synchronizeAfterRun="true">
        <exec>
            <option name="COMMAND" value="C:\cygwin64\bin\sh.exe" />
            <option name="PARAMETERS" value="-l -c &quot;cd /cygdrive/d/CLion_Projects/$FileDirName$; mpic++ $FileName$ -o $FileNameWithoutExtension$.exe&quot;" />
            <option name="WORKING_DIRECTORY" value="$ProjectFileDir$" />
        </exec>
    </tool>
    <tool name="mpirun" description="Runner for MPI" showInMainMenu="true" showInEditor="true" showInProject="true" showInSearchPopup="true" disabled="false" useConsole="true" showConsoleOnStdOut="false" showConsoleOnStdErr="false" synchronizeAfterRun="true">
        <exec>
            <option name="COMMAND" value="C:\cygwin64\bin\sh.exe" />
            <option name="PARAMETERS" value="-l -c &quot;cd /cygdrive/d/Clion_Projects/$FileDirName$; mpirun -np $Prompt$ -bind-to core:overload-allowed $FileNameWithoutAllExtensions$&quot;" />
            <option name="WORKING_DIRECTORY" value="$ProjectFileDir$" />
        </exec>
    </tool>
</toolSet>
```

- in this file `MPI.xml` find and replace 2 occurences of
  `d/CLion_Projects` with your own path to directory with CLion projects
- make sure that option COMMAND has correct value (path to `sh.exe`
  in `cygwin64\bin` folder)
- notice that `D:\something` must be `d/something` and of course avoid spaces in path

This file will integrate external tool for MPI C++ compiler `mpic++` and Runner for MPI `mpirun`.
By the way, full instructions for how to set up MPI into Clion over [here](https://github.com/lukasMega/other/wiki/mpi_clion_win).